# Show that domain of maximum solution to ODE $x'=1/(t^2+x^2)$ is unbounded on the right

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $f(t,x)=1/(t^2+x^2)$ for $t,x>0$. Let $u\colon J\to\mathbb{R}$ be the maximum solution of the initial value problem $$x'=f(t,x),\quad x(1)=1.$$ Show that $[1,\infty[\subseteq J$.

I know that $x(t)$ tends to a limit $\leq 1+\frac{\pi}{4}$ for $t\to\infty$, and I am familiar with the proof of the Picard-Lindelöf-theorem and the theorem of the unique non-extendable solution.

How could I show that there is no upper bound for $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying "the above initial value problem has a solution on $[1,\beta]$"?

Comment: How do you define maximum solution?

Comment: A solution is defined on an interval containing $1$ ($=t_0$). A solution is "bigger" than another solution if its domain is a super-set of the domain of the other solution. A maximum solution is non-extendable.

Comment: Look at the section labeled [Sufficient condition for $\mathrm{Dom}(y) = \mathbb{R}$](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/Maximum_domain_of_solution). Sadly, it's missing a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not clear whether this equation is just a model case to study the general theory, or if this specific solution with the specific starting value at $t_0=1$ is of interest. Yes, it does converge to a limit, and the upper bound $1+\pi/4$ for that limit is surprisingly sharp: a more precise value would be $1.729444022232888$.
In fact, we could even solve that analytically, in terms of parabolic cylinder functions of complex argument, though the formulas would be somewhat unwieldy. So I'll just give an outline. First off, we can study the inverse function, i.e. $t$ as a function of $x$. Obviously, the differential equation will read $$t'=x^2+t^2.$$ With the standard substitution $t=-u'/u$, where we can assume $u(x_0)=u(1)=1$, we arrive at $$u''=-x^2u$$ with $u(1)=1$ and $u'(1)=-1.$ Since $u'(1)=-1$ and $u''(x)<0$ as long as $u(x)>0,$ we see that $u(x)\le1-(x-1),$ so $u$ must have a zero $x_1<2$, where $t(x)$ "explodes", i.e. $t(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow x_1$. And that means that the inverse function has domain at least $[1,\infty)$ and converges to $x_1.$ The zero of $u(x)$ can be easily found by Newton iteration, since the standard methods for solving a differential equation of second order give $u',$ too. A nice detail: since $u''(x_1)=-x^2_1u(x_1)=0,$ Newton iteration converges cubically (that's how the above value of $x_1$ was determined).
Here, $u(x)$ is an entire function, so its Taylor series converges rapidly, and I think that would be the perfect tool to calculate everything one could possibly want to know about $u(x), t(x)$ or $x(t)$.